# How to count recurrence of objects in collection object. PHP/Laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

Im using this laravel function to get all the invoices created during the past 30 days:

```
$invoice = Invoices::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subMonth())->get();
```

That function return a collection of objects, what I want is to obtain an array of [creation day => how many where created on that day] for each one of the objects.

I was reading about array_count_values but that function doesn't work with collection objects.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be looking for the `groupBy` method. It allows you to group the results into a collection of collections. For example:

```
$invoiceGroup = Invoices::where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subMonth())
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(function($invoice) {
        return $invoice->created_at->format('d-M-y');
    });
```

Now, all your invoices are grouped together based on their created_at date.

```
foreach ($invoiceGroup as $date => $subGroup) {
    echo $date . ': ' . $subGroup->count();
}
```

This will echo out the created_at date and the number of invoices for that date. To get the individual invoices:

```
foreach ($invoiceGroup as $date => $subGroup) {
    foreach ($subGroup as $invoice) {
        // Access individual invoices
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what a I did to resolve my problem:

```
foreach ($invoice as $key => $value) {
        $date = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value->created_at);
        $result[$value->quote_number] = $date->day;
    }
```

Then i used `array_count_values($result)` to get what I wanted, maybe there is a builtin function to do what I needed thats why I wont choose this as the answer for now.

Comment: Thomas Kim's answer uses the groupBy method that is built into the Collection class.